# spring doesn't execute javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

I use Spring MVC 3 in my project.

This is my AddressController :

```
@Controller
public class AddressController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddressController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView init(
       @RequestParam(value="language",required=false,defaultValue="fr") String language){
               Locale locale = new Locale(language);
               logger.info("here");
               String[] isoCountries = locale.getISOCountries();

               Map<String,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();

               for(String isoCountry : isoCountries){
                      Locale countryLoc = new Locale(language, isoCountry);
                      String name = countryLoc.getDisplayCountry(locale);

                      if(!"".equals(name)){
                             treeMap.put(name,name);
                      }
                }

                Map<String,String> tree = new TreeMap<String,String>(treeMap);
                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("address");
                modelAndView.addObject("address",new Address());
                modelAndView.addObject("countriesList", tree);

                return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

The first time, when I executed /address, it's going well to my controller and it returns my address.jsp by executing the javascript in this last one. But when I execute /address?language=fr or /address?language=en, the javascript code of my address.jsp is not executed.

This is a part of my address.jsp :

```
 <%@page import="org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="forms" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
 <%@page import="com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.Internationale"%>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import="java.util.Locale" %> 
 <%@ page import="java.util.List" %> 
 <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %> 
 <%@ page import="java.util.Collections" %> 
 <html>
 <head>
      <jsp:include page="ressources.jsp"></jsp:include>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/320x480/portrait/address.css" />

      <%! Internationale internationale = Internationale.getInstance(); %>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     //checkParams();
     alert("here");
     var unit = "em";
     alert("here2");
     $("#backButton").attr("href","/index");

     $('#validationBtn').click(function(){

            var streetName = $('#streetName').val();
            var streetNumber = $('#streetNumber').val();
            var zipCode = $('#zipCode').val();
            var city = $('#city').val();
            var country = $('#country').val();

            var ref = "MyServlet?streetName="+streetName+"&streetNumber="+streetNumber+"&zipCode="+zipCode+"&city="+city+"&country="+country;

            $(this).attr("href",ref);

       });
     });

//rest of the script
</script>
<body>
  <a id="backButton" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"
    data-ajax="false"> 
    <spring:message code="backButton"/>
</a></div>

 //rest of the code
</body>
```

Comment: Please show `ressources.jsp`.

Comment: Spring does not execute the javascript. The aim of your JSP is to generate your HTML/JS code that will be sent to the client. Then the client executes the javascript. You should try to see what the client receives in the second case.

Comment: the OP didnt mean that Spring himself exceutes te the javascript, he should have say that "the javascript is not excecuted in his spring application". my adive is to open firebug, you might have a javascript error somewhere, this is why your javascript is not executed

Answer (score -2):

In web MVC spring serves as server side technology. Javascript is client (browser) side technology, thus Spring "cannot" execute javascript.

Comment: Although this is correct, OP states that in one request the javascript is executed and it isn't in the other. This answer is not useful.